# s3api - query by size appears to be not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The following returns me the data:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "buket_name" --prefix "file_name_prefix" --query "Contents[?Size<'99999999999999']"
```

At the same time, this returns nothing:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "buket_name" --prefix "file_name_prefix" --query "Contents[?Size>'1']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JMESPath Specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#filterexpressions), the parameters should be quoted with back-ticks (`).

However, this seems to interfere with the command-line, so they need to be escape with a backslash, as did the greater-than operator.

The following commands worked for me on a Mac:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query Contents[?Size\>\`1\`].Key

aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query Contents[?Size==\`305\`].Key
```

Comment: Thank you very much for noticing it!

Interestingly, single quotes work fine for "less then" operation, not not for "more then". Changing single quotes to back-ticks solved the problem:

    aws s3api list-objects --bucket "buket_name" --prefix "file_name_prefix" --query "Contents[?Size>\`10000\`]"